# Working SharedPreference to make button unclickable after a certain number of clicks in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this working code I got from SO, but the original poster failed to add one thing.

This code is working fine, but it does not save to user device using shared preference.

I am using this code in a fragment java class, the code makes a button unclickable after a particular number of clicks, help me with the Shared preference to save the clicks, so that this function can work even when user restarts the app

```
Integer maxclicks = 3; Integer currentnumber = 0;
if (currentnumber == maxclicks) {
                    itemChoice.setEnabled(false);

                } else {
                    currentnumber = currentnumber + 1;

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ChangeMode.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
```

I tried to use this shared preference, but it did not work, Cannot resolve method 'getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, ?)'
Cannot resolve symbol 'MODE_PRIVATE'
Cannot resolve symbol 'clicks'

Also I am implementing this code in a fragment.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
               editor.putInt("clicks", clicks);
               editor.apply();
```

Full Code

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Constants {

    private Preference recentlyDeletedPreference, balancePreference, balanceHistoryPreference, logoutPreference, itemContactUs, aboutPreference, changePassword, itemServices, itemTerms, itemThanks, itemReferralsList, itemBlackList, itemNotifications, itemDeactivateAccount, itemPrivacy, itemDark, itemChoice;
    private CheckBoxPreference allowComments, allowMessages, allowGalleryComments;

    private SwitchPreference mSwitch;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    int mAllowComments, mAllowMessages, mAllowGalleryComments;

    LinearLayout aboutDialogContent;
    TextView aboutDialogAppName, aboutDialogAppVersion, aboutDialogAppCopyright;

    private Boolean loading = false;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    Integer maxclicks = 3; Integer currentnumber = 0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setRetainInstance(true);

        initpDialog();

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        Preference pref = findPreference("settings_version");

        pref.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name) + " v" + getString(R.string.app_version));

        pref = findPreference("settings_logout");

        pref.setSummary(App.getInstance().getUsername());

//        pref = findPreference("settings_copyright_info");
//
//        pref.setSummary(APP_COPYRIGHT + " © " + APP_YEAR);

        recentlyDeletedPreference = findPreference("settings_recently_deleted");

        recentlyDeletedPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), RecentlyDeletedActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        balancePreference = findPreference("settings_balance");

        balancePreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), BalanceActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        balanceHistoryPreference = findPreference("settings_balance_history");

        balanceHistoryPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), BalanceHistoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        logoutPreference = findPreference("settings_logout");
        aboutPreference = findPreference("settings_version");
        changePassword = findPreference("settings_change_password");
        itemDeactivateAccount = findPreference("settings_deactivate_account");
        itemServices = findPreference("settings_services");
        itemTerms = findPreference("settings_terms");
        itemThanks = findPreference("settings_thanks");
        itemBlackList = findPreference("settings_blocked_list");
        itemReferralsList = findPreference("settings_referrals_list");
        itemNotifications = findPreference("settings_push_notifications");
        itemPrivacy = findPreference("settings_privacy");
        itemDark = findPreference("settings_dark");
        itemChoice = findPreference("choicePref");
        itemContactUs = findPreference("settings_contact_us");

        itemContactUs.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SupportActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemPrivacy.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PrivacySettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemDark.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DarkModeSet.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemChoice.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

               
                SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt("clicks", maxclicks); // Put count in onPause. we don't want to do this whenever we click the button to avoid resource westage.
                editor.apply();

                if (currentnumber == maxclicks) {
                    itemChoice.setEnabled(false);

                } else {
                    currentnumber = currentnumber + 1;
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ChangeMode.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }

                return true;

            }
        });

        itemNotifications.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationsSettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemBlackList.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), BlackListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemReferralsList.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemThanks.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("url", METHOD_APP_THANKS);
                i.putExtra("title", getText(R.string.settings_thanks));
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemTerms.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("url", METHOD_APP_TERMS);
                i.putExtra("title", getText(R.string.settings_terms));
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        aboutPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertDialog.setTitle(getText(R.string.action_about));

                aboutDialogContent = (LinearLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about_dialog, null);

                alertDialog.setView(aboutDialogContent);

                aboutDialogAppName = (TextView) aboutDialogContent.findViewById(R.id.aboutDialogAppName);
                aboutDialogAppVersion = (TextView) aboutDialogContent.findViewById(R.id.aboutDialogAppVersion);
                aboutDialogAppCopyright = (TextView) aboutDialogContent.findViewById(R.id.aboutDialogAppCopyright);

                aboutDialogAppName.setText(getString(R.string.app_name));
                aboutDialogAppVersion.setText("Version " + getString(R.string.app_version));
                aboutDialogAppCopyright.setText("Copyright © " + getString(R.string.app_year) + " " + getString(R.string.app_copyright));

//                    alertDialog.setMessage("Version " + APP_VERSION + "/r/n" + APP_COPYRIGHT);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                alertDialog.setNeutralButton(getText(R.string.action_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();

                return false;
            }
        });

        logoutPreference.setSummary(App.getInstance().getUsername());

        logoutPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertDialog.setTitle(getText(R.string.action_logout));

                alertDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.msg_action_logout));
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getText(R.string.action_no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getText(R.string.action_yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        loading = true;

                        showpDialog();

                        CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_LOGOUT, null,
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                        try {

                                            if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                                                Log.d("Logout", "Logout success");
                                            }

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                                            e.printStackTrace();

                                        } finally {

                                            loading = false;

                                            hidepDialog();

                                            App.getInstance().removeData();
                                            App.getInstance().readData();

                                            App.getInstance().setNotificationsCount(0);
                                            App.getInstance().setMessagesCount(0);
                                            App.getInstance().setId(0);
                                            App.getInstance().setUsername("");
                                            App.getInstance().setFullname("");

                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                loading = false;

                                hidepDialog();
                            }
                        }) {

                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);
                                params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
                                params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());

                                return params;
                            }
                        };

                        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(VOLLEY_REQUEST_SECONDS), DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

                        jsonReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);

                        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();

                return true;
            }
        });

        changePassword.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ChangePasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemDeactivateAccount.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DeactivateActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        itemServices.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ServicesActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                return true;
            }
        });

        if (!FACEBOOK_AUTHORIZATION) {

            PreferenceCategory headerGeneral = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("header_general");

            headerGeneral.removePreference(itemServices);
        }

        allowComments = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("allowComments");

        allowComments.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                if (newValue instanceof Boolean) {

                    Boolean value = (Boolean) newValue;

                    if (value) {

                        mAllowComments = 1;

                    } else {

                        mAllowComments = 0;
                    }

                    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

                        setAllowComments();

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.msg_network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });


        allowGalleryComments = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("allowGalleryComments");

        allowGalleryComments.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                if (newValue instanceof Boolean) {

                    Boolean value = (Boolean) newValue;

                    if (value) {

                        mAllowGalleryComments = 1;

                    } else {

                        mAllowGalleryComments = 0;
                    }

                    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

                        setAllowGalleryComments();

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.msg_network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        allowMessages = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("allowMessages");

        allowMessages.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

                if (newValue instanceof Boolean) {

                    Boolean value = (Boolean) newValue;

                    if (value) {

                        mAllowMessages = 1;

                    } else {

                        mAllowMessages = 0;
                    }

                    if (App.getInstance().isConnected()) {

                        setAllowMessages();

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.msg_network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        checkAllowComments(App.getInstance().getAllowComments());
        checkAllowGalleryComments(App.getInstance().getAllowGalleryComments());
        checkAllowMessages(App.getInstance().getAllowMessages());
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            loading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("loading");

        } else {

            loading = false;
        }

        if (loading) {

            showpDialog();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroyView() {

        super.onDestroyView();

        hidepDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean("loading", loading);
    }

    public void checkAllowComments(int value) {

        if (value == 1) {

            allowComments.setChecked(true);
            mAllowComments = 1;

        } else {

            allowComments.setChecked(false);
            mAllowComments = 0;
        }
    }

    public void checkAllowGalleryComments(int value) {

        if (value == 1) {

            allowGalleryComments.setChecked(true);
            mAllowGalleryComments = 1;

        } else {

            allowGalleryComments.setChecked(false);
            mAllowGalleryComments = 0;
        }
    }

    public void checkAllowMessages(int value) {

        if (value == 1) {

            allowMessages.setChecked(true);
            mAllowMessages = 1;

        } else {

            allowMessages.setChecked(false);
            mAllowMessages = 0;
        }
    }

    public void setAllowComments() {

        loading = true;

        showpDialog();

        CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_SET_ALLOW_COMMENTS, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {

                            if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                                App.getInstance().setAllowComments(response.getInt("allowComments"));

                                checkAllowComments(App.getInstance().getAllowComments());
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {

                            loading = false;

                            hidepDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                loading = false;

                hidepDialog();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);
                params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
                params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());
                params.put("allowComments", Integer.toString(mAllowComments));

                return params;
            }
        };

        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

    public void setAllowGalleryComments() {

        loading = true;

        showpDialog();

        CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_SET_ALLOW_GALLERY_COMMENTS, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {

                            if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                                App.getInstance().setAllowGalleryComments(response.getInt("allowGalleryComments"));

                                checkAllowGalleryComments(App.getInstance().getAllowGalleryComments());
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {

                            loading = false;

                            hidepDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                loading = false;

                hidepDialog();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);
                params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
                params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());
                params.put("allowGalleryComments", Integer.toString(mAllowGalleryComments));

                return params;
            }
        };

        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

    public void setAllowMessages() {

        loading = true;

        showpDialog();

        CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_SET_ALLOW_MESSAGES, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {

                            if (!response.getBoolean("error")) {

                                App.getInstance().setAllowMessages(response.getInt("allowMessages"));

                                checkAllowMessages(App.getInstance().getAllowMessages());
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {

                            loading = false;

                            hidepDialog();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                loading = false;

                hidepDialog();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);
                params.put("accountId", Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()));
                params.put("accessToken", App.getInstance().getAccessToken());
                params.put("allowMessages", Integer.toString(mAllowMessages));

                return params;
            }
        };

        App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }

    protected void initpDialog() {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading));
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    protected void showpDialog() {

        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    protected void hidepDialog() {

        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in line `this.getSharedPreferences(...` means "this class". `getSharedPreferences` is a method from `Context`, so "this class" must `extends Context`, as `Activity` or `Service` do. `Fragment` doesn't extend `Context`, but can fetch it using e.g. `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()`, so proper call inside `Fragment` would be

```
SharedPreferences prefs = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'requireContext()' and Cannot resolve symbol 'MODE_PRIVATE' when I use this sir, for this code, do you think I need to add a variable to call this code usually added after the public class before oncreate method for this code to work, I also got this SharedPreference code from SO

Comment: at first: post WHOLE code of `Fragment`. initialisation of `SharedPreferences` must be done inside a method, e.g. `onCreate` for `Activity` or `onCreateView` for `Fragment`. `SharedPreferences prefs = ...` must be placed inside one of them, not straight inside class

Comment: I have posted fragment whole code, i am trying to implement the onclick listener for click count here itemChoice.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

Comment: ok, I see this snippet, and what is wrong with it now? you should also set initial enabled state of `itemChoice`, not only inside click listener (read `"clicks"` value before setting `OnPreferenceClickListener`) and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

That's because the SharedPreferences is not an attribute from Fragment, it's actually from Activity, so in order to get it from a fragment you can do it like this:

```java
this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: See screenshot of how i implemented it with this answer, but still getting error https://snipboard.io/IkMZWm.jpg

Comment: That's because you're trying it within an *anonymous object*. In this case, you have to do *YourFragmentName*.this.getActivity()

Comment: okay that solved the first line or error what about this Cannot resolve symbol 'MODE_PRIVATE'

Comment: use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: Thanks solved, just 1 more issue, you have the correct answers and this should help others having issues with using sharedPreference in fragment, the last line of error the sharedPreferenc code which stores the number of clicks in a button is this "
Cannot resolve symbol 'clicks', "

Comment: Did you check my code will it work with this shared preference

Comment: check @OGx09 answer

Answer (score 0):

`this` is referring to your fragment instead of your activity/activity's context. So replace it with `getActivity()`/`requiredActivity()`. Also, I've provided a complete working code that would help you achieve what you want.

```
    int maxclicks = 3;
    int clicks =0;
    SharedPreferences prefs = requiredActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                   editor.putInt("clicks", clicks); // Put count in onPause. we don't want to do this whenever we click the button to avoid resource westage.
                   editor.apply();
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        int clicks = prefs.getInt("clicks", 0); // Read saved value
        itemChoice.setEnabled(clicks <maxclicks) //Disable button once the count gets to 3.
    }

itemChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        clicks+=1;
        itemChoice.setEnabled(clicks <maxclicks) 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but one thing,  Cannot resolve method 'requiredActivity' in 'SettingsFragment'

Comment: Also see screenshot https://snipboard.io/NLS86n.jpg

Comment: That's because you're yet to upgrade to `Androidx`...Replace `requiredActivity` with `getActivity()`, and pass default value to `getInt()`. For example: `pref.getInt("clicks", 0);`.

Comment: Thanks that helped, the last place with error now is the onresume method, please check https://snipboard.io/6jV3u9.jpg i don't fully understand what you say about pref.getInt("clicks", 0); and what change to make in ur code

Comment: Error says "Expected 2 arguments but found 1"

Comment: Please read my previous comment again. Just add `0` after `"clicks"`. I added an example. Lastly, don't forget the comma.

Comment: Thank you, it helped, so what do i add to the onclick listener button to make the click count

Comment: I have updated my answer. Pay attention to global `clicks`. Also, you can set text in onclick method if you want to show the count to your users.

Comment: Thank you for the time you have spent providing solution for me, it is really very important to me, i have implemented all codes as you provided, but when i launch the activity the app crashes, here is the the screenshot of the button where i placed onclick listener https://snipboard.io/E5F0hN.jpg here is the screenshot of onpause and onresume implementation https://snipboard.io/gfwF0e.jpg and this is the variables https://snipboard.io/jkvCuO.jpg

Comment: This is different from what you requested in your question, hence I'll stop here.

Comment: I believe you understood my question and you said your answer is the full working code, so I have replaced my existing code with yours hoping to achieve the same result "A way to limit users click on a button" and i thought your full working code will work for this.